# Is there a better shortcut for "move to next suggestion" in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

In Xcode, if I type nsmut then escape, I'm offered a number of NSMutable suggestions (NSMutableArray, NSMutableSet, etc). I use the arrow keys to get the one I want. This forces me to take my fingers off the home keys.

I was wondering if there's another keyboard shortcut to select the next and previous selection in the dropdown menu that appears. If not, is there a way to add a keyboard shortcut for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> will switch between suggestions.

Comment: Killer tip :) I never knew there was an alternate way to do this.